# SQL or SSIS to find missing date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, common-table-expression

I have an Agreement table and a Plan table. Plans are a child of agreements, and have a FK reference to them.

All of the plans of the same agreement should fill up the entire span of the agreement. However, there are some missing plans in the agreements.

Is there anyway in SQL OR SSIS to get a list of "missing" plans?

Agreement Table

```
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Agreement Id | Agreement Start Date | Agreement End Date |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|            1 | 1/1/2010             | 12/31/2016         |
+--------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

Plan Table

```
+--------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
| Agreement Id | Plan Id | Plan Start Date | Plan End Date |
+--------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
|            1 |       1 | 1/1/2010        | 12/31/2010    |
|            1 |       2 | 1/1/2012        | 12/31/2012    |
|            1 |       3 | 1/1/2014        | 12/31/2016    |
+--------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Desired Plan Table

```
+--------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
| Agreement Id | Plan Id | Plan Start Date | Plan End Date |
+--------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
|            1 |       1 | 1/1/2010        | 12/31/2010    |
|            1 |       4 | 1/1/2011        | 12/31/2011    |
|            1 |       2 | 1/1/2012        | 12/31/2012    |
|            1 |       5 | 1/1/2013        | 12/31/2013    |
|            1 |       3 | 1/1/2014        | 12/31/2016    |
+--------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
```

So essentially, I want to get the missing plans for the Agreement 1 which would be these rows:

```
+--------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
| Agreement Id | Plan Id | Plan Start Date | Plan End Date |
+--------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
|            1 |       4 | 1/1/2011        | 12/31/2011    |
|            1 |       5 | 1/1/2013        | 12/31/2013    |
+--------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Any solution that involves SQL or SSIS would be great!

Comment: Mysql is a different product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is written for MS SQL Server, so you'll likely need to adjust the date functions if you're coding for MySQL, but I believe this should work. I don't think that I covered the situation of a missing plan at the start of the agreement, so I'll give that some thought and add code for that shortly:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, 1, P.end_date) AS start_date,
    COALESCE(DATEADD(DAY, -1, P3.start_date), A.end_date) AS end_date
FROM
    dbo.Agreements A
INNER JOIN dbo.Plans P ON
    P.agreement_id = A.agreement_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Plans P2 ON P2.agreement_id = A.agreement_id AND P2.start_date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, P.end_date)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Plans P3 ON P3.agreement_id = A.agreement_id AND P3.start_date > P.end_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Plans P4 ON P4.agreement_id = A.agreement_id AND P4.start_date BETWEEN P.end_date AND P3.start_date AND P4.plan_id <> P3.plan_id
WHERE
    P.end_date <> A.end_date AND
    P2.agreement_id IS NULL AND
    P4.agreement_id IS NULL
```

This method should also catch missing start and end plans, but uses the windowed function ROW_NUMBER to line stuff up. You can do it without ROW_NUMBER, but it's much more complex. I'm also not sure that there isn't a much simpler way of doing this in SQL, but this was the first thing that came to my mind as I started typing:

```
;WITH CTE_MissingEndDates AS
(
    SELECT agreement_id, missing_end_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY agreement_id ORDER BY missing_end_date) AS row_num
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.agreement_id,
            DATEADD(DAY, -1, P1.start_date) AS missing_end_date
        FROM
            dbo.Agreements A
        INNER JOIN dbo.Plans P1 ON P1.agreement_id = A.agreement_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Plans P2 ON P2.agreement_id = A.agreement_id AND P2.end_date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, P1.start_date)
        WHERE
            P1.start_date > A.start_date
        UNION
        SELECT A2.agreement_id, A2.end_date FROM dbo.Agreements A2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Plans WHERE agreement_id = A2.agreement_id AND end_date = A2.end_date)
    ) SQ
),
CTE_MissingStartDates AS
(
    SELECT agreement_id, missing_start_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY agreement_id ORDER BY missing_start_date) AS row_num
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.agreement_id,
            DATEADD(DAY, 1, P1.end_date) AS missing_start_date
        FROM
            dbo.Agreements A
        INNER JOIN dbo.Plans P1 ON P1.agreement_id = A.agreement_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Plans P2 ON P2.agreement_id = A.agreement_id AND P2.start_date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, P1.end_date)
        WHERE
            P1.end_date < A.end_date
        UNION
        SELECT A2.agreement_id, A2.start_date FROM dbo.Agreements A2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Plans WHERE agreement_id = A2.agreement_id AND start_date = A2.start_date)
    ) SQ
)
SELECT
    MSD.missing_start_date,
    MED.missing_end_date
FROM
    CTE_MissingStartDates MSD
INNER JOIN CTE_MissingEndDates MED ON
    MED.agreement_id = MSD.agreement_id AND
    MED.row_num = MSD.row_num
```